# Django get plain value of Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```py
def MyModel(models.Model):
  other = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel, db_column='other', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_constraint=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

The problem is that maybe a value in `other` field (which is a **string value**) of the model `MyModel` could not be in `OtherModel` so when I do, for example:

```py
inst = MyModel.objects.first()  # Gets any (with an "invalid" key in other)
inst.other
```

It threw:

> others.models.OtherModel.DoesNotExist: OtherModel matching query does not exist.

I'd like that, in case that it doesn't exists, get the plain value of the `other` field. How could I achieve that?

Any kind of help would be really appreciated

Comment: this is exactly what `db_constraint` aims to do: guarantee referential integrity.

Comment: But it's set to `False`, so it shouldn't break when if doesn't exist, should it?

Comment: Reading the documentation again I realised that it raises the exception if it doesn't exist. It makes no sense, if I set it to `True` it breaks on migrations as the key doesn't exist in `OtherModel`, if I set to `False` it breaks when tried to retrieve as the key doesn't exist in `OtherModel`.... How could i get the plain value of the column without raising an exception on retireval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encapsulate the logic in a property (or method):

```
def MyModel(models.Model):
    other = models.ForeignKey(
        OtherModel,
        db_column='other',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        db_constraint=False,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    @property
    def other_or_value(self):
        try:
            return self.other
        except OtherModel.DoesNotExist:
            return self.other_id
```

and then thus use:

```
mymodelobject.other_or_value
```

I'm however not sure that this is a good idea. Now the method can return two types of objects, and typically, that makes processing the result more complicated. It also means that this is the same for the database: it can no longer guarantee referential integrity. While errors regarding referincing a non-existing object are annoying, the alternative of ignoring these is often worse.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've found that there's an implicit `_id` sufix ([doc link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)). I just need the plain value, the foreign key is only for fast retrieval when sorts using Django Rest framework which does not support sorting by a property value

Comment: @Genarito: yes, Django constructs an extra "field" (well it is not a database column) with the name `fieldname_id` that contains the value stored at the database side. You can use this as an attribute, field in ORM queries, etc.